# This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread,

Tags: uitableview, webview, swift2

I wonder if you can help as I am getting this error.
    2016-07-17 20:13:01.312 ShortGameGolfAcademy[17843:6735678] This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread, which can lead to engine corruption and weird crashes.  This will cause an exception in a future release.
 Stack:(

Now I think this has something to do with an embed YouTubeVideo code.

```
import UIKit

class ControlBackSwingViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var videoView: UIWebView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let youTubeUrl = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/TNY9xpW0idk"
    videoView.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true

    videoView.loadHTMLString("<iframe width=\"\(videoView.frame.width)\" height=\"\(videoView.frame.height)\" src=\"\(youTubeUrl)\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>", baseURL: nil)

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

Now I am going from a Static UITableView to a WebView in a Storyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting the code in question in this code block:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
    print("This is run on the main queue, after the previous code in outer block")
})
```

Comment: Ok I will try that. Thanks for your help Albert.

Comment: Unfortunately I am getting "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" with the following code

Comment: `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
            
            let youTubeUrl = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/-7XA__olOg0"
        self.videoView.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
        
        self.videoView.loadHTMLString("<iframe width=\"\(self.videoView.frame.width)\" height=\"\(self.videoView.frame.height)\" src=\"\(youTubeUrl)\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>", baseURL: nil)
            
            print("This is run on the main queue, after the previous code in outer block")
        })`

Comment: Also, when I run the the App on my iPhone I am losing sound.  I can only hear the sound through my head phones. The code I have is `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in let youTubeUrl = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/Qhx4mix_Pcg"
        self.videoView.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
        self.videoView.loadHTMLString("<iframe width=\"\(self.videoView.frame.width)\" height=\"\(self.videoView.frame.height)\" src=\"\(youTubeUrl)\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>", baseURL: nil)
})`